# why am i not able to access my node red with my public ip

Tags: node.js, networking, node-red

I've been trying very hard to access my *node red* on *pi* over internet. I'm using my public **ip : 1880 (node red port to connect)**; I've done port forwarding over my *binatone router*, with service port as *1880* and internal port as *1880* with local IP. Please, I'm running out of time. I've tried local tunnel but its not working.

> (cli is stuck at lt -p 1880 -o)

I don't want to use **ngrok** as it'll start a new tunnel every time my *pi* reboots. I think my router is not really opening up the ports, I've tried checking that with **portchecker.co** its showing that my port is closed. Is it my router? I'm very confused please help me out i visited a ton of websites but couldn't find anything related to my problem, and I disabled my firewall too.

Comment: Is your Pi accessible or does a firewall on the Pi prevent access...?

Comment: im able to access it over lan, does that mean my firewall of pi allowing it? should i disable firewall on my pi too?

Comment: If external tools are showing that the port is closed (on your router) then it's most likely the firewall on the router. But asking how to set your router up is off topic for Stack Overflow (it may be on topic on Super User)

Comment: i have disabled my router firewall totally